# Change Style of IDLE Python

Tags: themes, python-idle

I want to change the style i.e. theme, button style, font and other items. I can change its style by my own if I can locate the `IDLE.py` file. So I want to know either of 2 things
--> Where is IDLE located?
--> or How to change everything of it?
Please Help me in getting any of these!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDLE application consists of multiple files in `<python-dir>/Lib/idlelib`.  The idle.py file in that directory is just a startup file.

The editor/shell font can be configured in the Fonts tab of the settings dialog open by Options => Configure IDLE (or IDLE => Setting on macOS).

There is no setting to change the style of widgets.  IDLE currently uses ttk widgets when possible.  It you edit the idlelib files at all extensively, I suggest you make a copy of idlelib so you can make a diff between the edited and original copies.